# Include XML Field in an XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

I have an XML configuration file, i want to pull one of the fields from that file and include it on my XSL.

Here are the examples that I have come across:

```
<xsl:template match="">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Page</title>
      <!-- CSS styles included here -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('style.xml')/style" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- ... -->
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

But this doesn't solve my problem as it includes the whole .xml file.  I only want one of the properties in the xml file to be included so i would have to parse it inside the xsl and include only that node.  How do i do that?

Thank you

**Update from comments**

> If I include the following line in my
>   XSL:
>
> ```
> <xsl:copy-of select="document('cmsaENV.xml')/STR_ENV_PROPS/text()"/>
> ```
>
> And my xml contains:
>
> ```
> <STR_ENV_PROPS value="c:/apps/cit/deploy/d_cmsadm/cmsa_applicationEnv.xml"/>
> ```
>
> Then the string
>   `"c:/apps/cit/deploy/d_cmsadm/cmsa_applicationEnv.xm"`
>   will be placed inside my xsl? Is this
>   correct?

Comment: I edited your question to show the code, but some of the tags were messed up, most notably `xsl:template`.  You may want to edit for your full intent to come across.

Comment: What is the contents of the style.xml file?  What do you expect as the result of the 'style' element selection?

Comment: No, text() will return the text between tags, but not from attributes (so not from the 'value' attribute in your example).  If you leave out '/text(), you should get the complete <STR_ENV_PROPS> in the result.  But from the first post I thought you did not want that to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure to really get what you want, but if you want to include only the *contents* of the `<style>` element (and not the element itself), replace

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('style.xml')/style" />
```

with

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('style.xml')/style/text()" />
```

`text()` selects the textual content of the `style` element in the imported document.

EDIT: if instead of the textual contents you want the value of an attribute, you need something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string(document('style.xml')/style/@someAttribute)" />
```

Note that you need to convert the attribute into a regular text string, which I do with the `string()` function.

Comment: Or, if you want just the entire contents of the `<style>` tag without the tag itself, use `document('style.xml')/style/*`

Comment: So just to re-iterate, with the technique above if I include the following line in my XSL:  <xsl:copy-of select="document('cmsaENV.xml')/STR_ENV_PROPS/text()" />  and my xml contains:  <STR_ENV_PROPS value="c:/apps/cit/deploy/d_cmsadm/cmsa_applicationEnv.xml" /> then the string "c:/apps/cit/deploy/d_cmsadm/cmsa_applicationEnv.xm" will be placed inside my xsl?  Is this correct?  Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisJ: Please, correct the expression according new updated question.

Comment: If you want the contents of the `value` attribute you need `string(document('cmsaENV.xml')/STR_ENV_PROPS/@value)`.

Comment: @ChrisJ: `xsl:value-of` is the proper instruction for output text nodes.